# Is there a way to make it so that my Xamarin Forms application only works in Portrait mode?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that looks good in portrait mode but doesn't look good in landscape mode.

Is there any way within forms or through custom renderers that I can set the application so that it always sets itself into portrait mode?

Not sure if this helps, but I am using Xamarin Essentials, just in case there's a way to do it with the functionality that Essentials offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for this one in android

```
Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

In android MainActivity:

```
  namespace Namespace.Droid
{
    [Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait , ...]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
     ...
```

In Ios Info.pList:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
```

make sure that only the portrait orientation remains

Answer (score 2):

Device screen orientation in xamarin is usually configured from Host(Android/iOS) project.

On iOS, device orientation is configured for applications using the Info.plist file.

[image: info.plist]

On Android, open MainActivity.cs and set the orientation using the attribute decorating the MainActivity class:

```
namespace MyRotatingApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyRotatingApp.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)] //This is what controls orientation
    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
    }
}
```

For more info, you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=macos)